# Error occurred when enabling [Plugin] v1.0 (Is it up to date?) spigot error

Tags: java, bukkit

So I was trying to code a plugin that adds extra armor and stuff that vanilla doesn't have. (emerald armor emerald sword etc) Intellij says that the method "setDisplayName" will cause a NullPointerException, and I think it does because whenever I try to run the plugin, I get this error:

```
    [12:39:07] [Server thread/INFO]: [ExtrasX] Enabling ExtrasX v1.0
    [12:39:07] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling ExtrasX v1.0 (Is it up to 
    date?)
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "[Ljava.lang.String;.clone()" because 
    "this.rows" is null
    at org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe.getShape(ShapedRecipe.java:186) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.inventory.CraftShapedRecipe.fromBukkitRecipe(CraftShapedRecipe.java:33) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.addRecipe(CraftServer.java:1228) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at com.wasdnoob.extrasx.items.ItemManager.createEmeraldHelmet(ItemManager.java:60) ~[?:?]
    at com.wasdnoob.extrasx.items.ItemManager.init(ItemManager.java:26) ~[?:?]
    at com.wasdnoob.extrasx.ExtrasX.onEnable(ExtrasX.java:10) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:511) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:425) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:619) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:266) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1010) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:305) ~[spigot-1.17.1.jar:3227-Spigot-3c1fc60-a0a37f4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

Here is my item manager class:

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.NamespacedKey;
import org.bukkit.attribute.Attribute;
import org.bukkit.attribute.AttributeModifier;
import org.bukkit.inventory.EquipmentSlot;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemFlag;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.LeatherArmorMeta;

import java.util.UUID;

public class ItemManager {

    public static ItemStack emeraldhelmet;
    public static ItemStack emeraldchestplate;
    public static ItemStack emeraldleggings;
    public static ItemStack emeraldboots;

    public static void init() {
        createEmeraldHelmet();
        createEmeraldChestplate();
        createEmeraldLeggings();
        createEmeraldBoots();
    }

    public static void createEmeraldHelmet() {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("§2Emerald Helmet");
        LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta = (LeatherArmorMeta) meta;
        leatherArmorMeta.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        AttributeModifier armor = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armor", 3, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.HEAD);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR, armor);
        AttributeModifier armortoughness = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armortoughness", 2, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.HEAD);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR_TOUGHNESS, armortoughness);
        meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        emeraldhelmet = item;

        ShapedRecipe sr = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldhelmet"), item);
        sr.shape("EEE",
                "B B",
                "   ");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(sr);

        ShapedRecipe s = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldhelmet"), item);
        sr.shape("   ",
                "EEE",
                "B B");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(s);
    }

    public static void createEmeraldChestplate() {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("§2Emerald Chestplate");
        LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta = (LeatherArmorMeta) meta;
        leatherArmorMeta.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        AttributeModifier armor = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armor", 8, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.CHEST);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR, armor);
        AttributeModifier armortoughness = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armortoughness", 3, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.CHEST);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR_TOUGHNESS, armortoughness);
        meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        emeraldchestplate = item;

        ShapedRecipe sr = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldchestplate"), item);
        sr.shape("B B",
                "EBE",
                "EEE");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(sr);
    }

    public static void createEmeraldLeggings() {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("§2Emerald Leggings");
        LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta = (LeatherArmorMeta) meta;
        leatherArmorMeta.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        AttributeModifier armor = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armor", 6, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.LEGS);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR, armor);
        AttributeModifier armortoughness = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armortoughness", 3, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.LEGS);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR_TOUGHNESS, armortoughness);
        meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        emeraldleggings = item;

        ShapedRecipe sr = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldleggings"), item);
        sr.shape("BBB",
                "E E",
                "E E");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(sr);
    }

    public static void createEmeraldBoots() {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("§2Emerald Boots");
        LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta = (LeatherArmorMeta) meta;
        leatherArmorMeta.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        AttributeModifier armor = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armor", 3, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.FEET);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR, armor);
        AttributeModifier armortoughness = new AttributeModifier(UUID.randomUUID(), "generic.armortoughness", 2, AttributeModifier.Operation.ADD_NUMBER, EquipmentSlot.FEET);
        meta.addAttributeModifier(Attribute.GENERIC_ARMOR_TOUGHNESS, armortoughness);
        meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        emeraldboots = item;

        ShapedRecipe sr = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldboots"), item);
        sr.shape("E E",
                "B B",
                "   ");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(sr);

        ShapedRecipe s = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldboots"), item);
        sr.shape("   ",
                "E E",
                "B B");
        sr.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        sr.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(s);
    }
}
```

help pls

Answer (score 1):

You have two ShapedRecipe. One you named `sr` and one `s`. But you added the shape and the ingredients only to `sr` and not to `s`. So `s` has no ingredients and no shape! Change from row 55 to 59 `sr` to `s` like below:

```
    ShapedRecipe s = new ShapedRecipe(NamespacedKey.minecraft("emeraldhelmet"), item);
    s.shape("   ",
            "EEE",
            "B B");
    s.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
    s.setIngredient('B', Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
    Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(s);
```

PS: Your boots need the same change. xD